# Help with tool recommendation, to build a parse tree for C source code

Tags: programming, c, uml

I need a tool that can generate a tree for a C application. like walking through it to build which methods is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "best" is really subjective, but eclipse and eclipse CDT have loads of plugins.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468991/recommendations-for-uml-tool-to-model-c-qnx-eclipse-cdt-please) is probably relevant.

If you want a thing of absolute beauty shell out the money for Klockwork.

EDIT:Thought I would add [this](http://www.doxygen.nl/) since the user complained about requiring an IDE.  I would really rather do it from an IDE myself, but there are other options.

Comment: as i understand the thread you post it only let me to do the work by my self,but i need a tool that auto generate a tree only by giving it the source code of the application. i am trying to understand an application that written by some developer,and money is an issue.

Comment: generation of UML from code is EXACTLY what you are asking for

Comment: the procedure would be something like import the source code you're examining into an eclipse project and run any of the plug-ins listed

Comment: is there any apps other than eclipse that generate UML, sorry but am new in this field.

Comment: re-read my answer.  the link references both plug-ins and BoUML.  I added doxygen to the answer.  I'm not sure what else you could possibly be expecting

Comment: i found doxygen more useful. thank you ,and that was what am expecting. thank you agin